# Remove all system function with sed command

Tags: 16.04, c++, sed

I have cpp file I want to remove all system function inside this cpp file with sed command for example

```
int a;
cin>>a;
system(a);
system("dadad");
system('dad');
```

I want to remove all system function in above code is there any way that I can solve this problem with sed command

Answer (score 1):

This could get complicated but all your examples show one command per line with the `system` command starting at the beginning of the line.  In that case, it is relatively simple.  Here are three methods:

#### Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -v '^system(' file.cpp
int a;
cin>>a;
```

The regex `^system(` matches lines that begin with `system(`.  The `-v` option tells grep to remove the lines that match.

#### Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^system(/d' file.cpp
int a;
cin>>a;
```

The `d` command tells `sed` to delete any line that matches the regex `^system(`.

#### Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/^system\(/' file.cpp
int a;
cin>>a;
```

In awk, `!` is negation and `!/^system\(/` prints any line that does *not* match the regex `^system\(`.  (Unlike for the default forms of `grep` and `sed`, `(` is a regex-active in awk and we must escape it with a backslash in order to match an actual `(`.)